# git subtree pull says that the working tree has modifications, but git status says it doesn't. What gives?

Tags: git, subtree

If I do this in one of my repositories:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=frameworks/AquaticPrime --squash AquaticPrime
```

I get this:

```
Working tree has modifications.  Cannot add.
```

If I do this (in the same place, of course):

```
git status
```

I get this:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on here. The git status command implies that I don't have modifications, so I'm assuming that the git subtree pull is referring to modifications in a different branch related to the subtree, but it's not entirely clear.

Can anyone provide enlightenment?

Comment: From a quick look at the source, `git-subtree` prints that when `git diff-index HEAD --exit-code --quiet` exits "failure", i.e. changes exist. What happens if you run `git diff-index HEAD`?

Comment: You could also try the `-d` (debug) option.

Comment: When I run git diff-index HEAD, I get "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.". Similar output if I use the -d debug flag. 

So the question is, why would HEAD be unknown?

Comment: @BT I think you tried to use git subtree in a repo without any commits. Git should be enhanced to give a more useful error in this case. I just added an arbitrary commit to start the repo off, and `subtree` worked after that

Comment: I had the same message, but I still needed to pull master and my feature, then merge master to feature before I could pull the recent commits from the subtree.

Comment: We ran into this for kubernetes-csi/csi-release-tools which is a sub-module that gets shared by different other repos.

`-d` does not provide any insights into what's wrong.

git version 2.39.2

Comment: `git diff-index HEAD` reports nothing.

Comment: What helped is `git reset --hard` before invoking `git subtree pull`, but the root cause remains a mystery. The repo that is being pulled into is a clean fresh checkout.

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan I was struggling with this for two days and then read your comment. Now, it works. So strange. I wonder why git subtree is designed that way (=

Answer (score 47):

I just had the same problem.
From GIT source, error is thrown when command `git diff-index HEAD` returns result, even if `git status` says working tree is clean.

To avoid this error, in my case, I re-checkout the current branch of working tree , and everything seems OK : `git checkout <branch>`

It's a bit confused, but if someone can explain why ...

Comment: The description of the problem is great, but I need a bit more information to implement it...OH, you just meant simply to run "git checkout master" in the main (non-subtree) module. Great!

Comment: git checkout did not fix my problem but git reset did.

Answer (score 18):

`git reset --hard` fixed it to me

From `git reset --help`

> --hard Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are discarded.

Comment: use only if you are certain what `git reset --hard` does, you may lose work. maybe `git stash save --include-untracked` would be a safer way to go? (as you could retrieve the stashed work later)

Answer (score 14):

I got around this now. My problem seemed to me that the repository was brand new: I had never committed anything to it. Once I committed a file to the repo, I was able to move past this error.

However, using the command `git subtree add C:\gitTest\repos\subA -d --prefix subA` I got the new error:

`fatal just how do you expect me to merge 0 trees?`

After messing around for a minute, I figured out it requires that a specific revision be passed to it. So this command seems to have succeeded:

`git subtree add C:\gitTest\repos\subA HEAD -d --prefix subA`

And obviously you don't need the -d debug flag.

Comment: Thank you **very** much!! Your observation regarding problems with empty repository has turned out to be also valid in context of [this question about problems with `git tfs subtree add`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886008/how-to-manage-two-tfs-projects-in-one-git-repository/38081315#38081315). The exact error message was `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` and it was all about "missing HEAD" on master in empty repo.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem, when I:

- added a subtree;
- realized, I added it incorrectly (to a wrong directory);
- removed it with rm;
- tried to import it again (to the correct place).

Although `puppet diff` was -- correctly -- showing nothing, the `git diff-index HEAD` listed each of the files I just deleted as "deleted" -- even though I never commit-ed (much less push-ed) anything.

I believe, this is a bug in git (using 2.7.0 here)... Bug or not, the work-around is to switch to *any* other branch (with the usual `git checkout ....`) and then back to yours. Hope, this helps someone -- even if not the original asker.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, try to use Git Bash instead of PowerShell or cmd.exe.
This fixed the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error.  This was occurring on my feature branch.  The fix:

1. Pulled from feature branch remote to local
2. Pulled from master remote to local
3. Merged local master to feature branch, committed, and pushed to remote
4. Ran the `git subtree pull --prefix MySubdirection https://my/repository/url remotebranch --squash

I have no clue why I had to get master and merge to my feature branch, but that solved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with SourceTree. The problem was when I set up the subtree, I was selecting an existing folder. There was a warning but I ignored it. Setting up the subtree again but typing in a new folder name (one that doesn't exist yet) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all changes made to your local Git repository have been committed before attempting to execute Git commands that modify your repository, such as `git subtree add`. This will avoid any issues that might occur due to open commit

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this as the first commit in a project and it was weird (git branch) showed nothing. I made a tmp commit and then it worked

Answer (score -5):

Try to pull without `--squash` as it is described in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10698924/80480).

Comment: Thanks, I feel kind of rude not up-voting/ticking your answer, but the truth is that it's been so long that I don't use subtree any more, and I can't really test the answer to see if it works!

Comment: I have the same problem and removing --squash doesn't solve it.

Comment: I didn't use squash to begin with. In fact I don't even know why you would think it would work because the SO question you posted didn't ask about the message we're getting..