# git-subtree pull complications

Tags: git, merge, git-subtree

We have been trying to get [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) working on a project (with git version 1.7.9.4) and have run into a bit of a complication. Someone else previous added the subtree with this command some months ago:

```
git subtree add --prefix=foo git@example.com:foo.git master
```

Now there have been substantive changes to `foo` and we'd like to merge in those changes, ideally squashing them in. None of the files have been modified since they were imported.

I've tried three things to try and merge in the changes.

First:

```
git subtree pull --squash -P foo git@example.com:foo.git master
```

Which throws the exception: `Can't squash-merge: 'foo' was never added.`

Second:

```
git subtree pull -P foo git@example.com:foo.git master
```

This works (sort of), but has the issue of pulling in all of the commits and has conflicts with the files that have been modified.

Finally, I tried this:

```
git pull --squash -s subtree git@example.com:foo.git  master
```

This gives me the desired result, with the output `Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested` and all of the files showing up as modified (with the correct content).

Ideally I'd like to continue using first `git-subtree` version and get an output close to the last version.  If we have to use the last version consistently going forward, we will, but I am a little confused as to why the last one doesn't produce merge conflicts while the middle one does.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem, and in my case it seems to be due to the initial subtree commit being merge-squashed into the master branch.

Looking through the subtree source I found this: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh#L224

It looks like subtree greps your git log for `git-subtree-dir: foo` but doesn't find a suitable commit. Try `git log --grep="git-subtree-dir: foo/*\$"`, and if there's something weird with that commit, such as it being a merge commit, that could be the issue.

Just pulling without squashing worked for me, apart from the annoying merge conflicts. I did that in a temporary branch which I then `git merge --squash`ed into another branch to avoid a messier history. It could've been rebased instead too of course.

Comment: I had the same problem which turned out to have been caused by me missing a sub-folder in the prefix option when trying to pull. Adding this as a comment since the error message does not give any indication of this error and the troubleshooting led me here.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I had a related issue where I moved the subdir after adding the subtree into it, which seems to trip up this match

Comment: I had this problem, and it was due to our stashweb policy which squashes commits.  I was able to fix it by finding a subtree commit and using `git merge -s ours <commit>` to bring it into history.

Answer (score 3):

I've been experiencing the same error `Can't squash-merge: 'foo' was never added.` with sourcetree 1.7.0 whenever I do a pull on a subtree.
However, I believe my case is different because I'm using subdirectories.

Sourcetree does something as follows:
`git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false subtree pull -P dir1\subdir1 --squash remote-repo master`

And obviously, if we were to try it again in Git Bash (Git version 2.6.1.windows.1), it would be:
`git subtree pull -P "dir1\subdir1" --squash remote-repo master`

However that failed. The following also failed although the command syntax is fine:
`git subtree pull -P dir1/subdir1 --squash remote-repo master`

The solution I found to make it work is to use Git Bash with the following command:
`git subtree pull -P "dir1/subdir" --squash remote-repo master`

I guess that there is still some work to be done for Git's command-line processing engine.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens, if the current clone is a partial clone (e.g., when using `--depth=1`). This is the default at [GitHub Actions V2](https://github.com/actions/checkout).

In the case of GitHub actions, this can be configured when using `fetch-depth: 0` at the checkout step:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
          fetch-depth: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when the main repository and the subtree repository has different set of commits.

In my case I had updated the subtree from the local repository(using `git subtree pull --squash -P foo local/foo.git master`) and the local repository changes were never pushed to origin.

When I tried `git pull --squash -s subtree git@example.com:foo.git  master` after this, I started getting the error.

Just pushing the subtree repository solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Another case where this might happen is if this repository was "extracted" from another repository using `git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter subdir`.

Removing the subtree and adding it again worked for me in this case.