# Merging Upstream Repo with --Squash

Tags: git, github

I'm using a forked repo on GitHub and from time to time I need to merge in work on the real ("upstream") repo, as described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/).

I would love to squash their changes like this

```
git pull https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI.git MIDIFiles --squash
```

but... will my stuff be automatically merge-able with the upstream repo later? Or **will those squashed commits cause my repo to differ greatly from the upstream repo, even if *my* changes were very few?**

Comment: Using `--squash` is likely to increase the chance of getting merge conflicts, since git has to use an earlier common ancestor for later merges.  I can't see any reason why you would want to do this.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SvenMarnach as I'm working, the main repo is advancing by dozens of commits. They will have commits before and after what I'm doing. I want to keep my history clean, so I don't confuse what I'm working on. A cluttered git history is hard to read, and although I can probably grep it just fine, this is an additional hassle. Does that make sense?

Comment: Using `--squash` doesn't really make the history of *your* branch any cleaner.  You still get one commit per merge.

Comment: @SvenMarnach sorry, you're saying that when I pull the upstream branch, it comes into one commit? I thought it comes into my branch's history as a ton of different commits, some after and some before the current HEAD. No? I'm sure I'm not understanding something/anything. Any help helps, thank you!

Comment: Fetching from upstream will fetch the individual commits.  If you merge the upstream branch into your branch (e.g. `git merge upstream/master`), this will either create a single merge commit on your branch or perform a fast-forward, depending on whether you did any changes since the last merge. In the former case, `git log` for your branch will only show one merge commit, in the latter case it will show the individual upstream commits.  If you want to avoid the fast-forward , you can either use the `--no-ff` flag to `git merge` or `git pull`, or…

Comment: …rewind the previous merge using `git reset --hard HEAD^` (warning: this will throw away all local changes.  Stash first if you want to keep them) and then simply call `git merge` again.  You should only go for the latter option if you haven't published the first merge commit yet.

Comment: Thanks @SvenMarnach, I'm still digesting this but it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

[Even for subtree, a pull --squash can be troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10698924/6309)

That command is more used on the integrator side, when you merge a PR (Pull Request) branch into your original repo (in order to get only one commit).
See for instance "[Merging a PR (yours or contributors)](https://mahout.apache.org/developers/github.html#merging-a-pr-yours-or-contributors)"

> Remember that pull requests are equivalent to a remote github branch with potentially a multitude of commits.
>   In this case it is recommended to squash remote commit history to have one commit per issue, rather than merging in a multitude of contributor's commits.
>   In order to do that, as well as close the PR at the same time, it is recommended to use squash commits.

So in your case, it is recommended to *not* use squash.