# pull git subtree, working tree has modification

Tags: git-subtree

I've a remote repository let's call it *subrepo*. I want to include it as subtree in local repository, let's call it *mainrepo*. I'll put *subrepo* under the path 'subrepofold/'.

I added as usually the remote using:

```
git remote add subrepo git@remote.subrepo.git
```

On *mainrepo* I've only a branch (master). I added and committed all:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "message"
git status
```

> On branch master
>       nothing to commit, working directory clean

```
git diff-index HEAD --exit-code --quiet
```

Give me no output. Running:

```
git subtree pull --prefix="subrepofold" subrepo master --squash
```

I get the following message:

> Working tree has modifications.  Cannot add.

I know it seems to be the exact problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623351/git-subtree-pull-says-that-the-working-tree-has-modifications-but-git-status-sa), but none of the replies seems to resolve the problem.